# How to convert exceptions to errors and error messages when wrapping C++ classes API for C consumption?

Tags: c++, c, exception, language-binding

## The problem

Say you've got a C++ class.

Say you want to export its constructor(s) and methods to C.

Say you followed the advices given in the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1590534/566849) to the "[Wrapping C++ class API for C consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588788/wrapping-c-class-api-for-c-consumption)" question.

Now say your class constructor can throw one or more exceptions, which you want to catch on the C++ side before returning to the C world, whilst still giving the C user the chance to get information about the error that just happened.

### First approach

I could check that `MyClass_new()` returned a NULL pointer and then retrieve the "last error message" occurred in the library with a function, but when the constructor fails there's just no object to provide the right context for the error retrieval, therefore a global variable should be used to hold the last error which however undermines the reentrancy of the library.

### Second approach

Another possibility I can think of, **which is actually the solution I came up with**, is for the class to trap the exception inside the constructor itself, convert it to an error message and put the object into a "error state" of sort.

After each

```
MyClass myObj = MyClass_new();
```

the following check would be performed

```
if (MyClass_isInErrorState(myObj))
```

and the error message would be retrieved with the next statement

```
const char *error = MyClass_getLastError(myObj);
```

### Third approach

Another possibility I can think of is to pass a pointer to a buffer of a given size to each function that can fail, which would be filled up with the error message, but it looks messy.

How would you do it? Is there a de facto standard way of dealing with such issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replying to my own question.

I think I will go with a slightly modified second approach.

The constructor will return `BOOL` like all the other functions that can fail and will accept a `MyClass *` out parameter which will be set to some meaningful value even in case of error, so that `MyClass_getLastError(myObj)` could be used.

This gets rid of the extra `MyClass_isInErrorState()` function.

`MyClass` on the C side will be an opaque pointer and on the C++ side will be a pointer to a structure holding a pointer, possibly NULL, to the class' object and a buffer of sorts that contains the error string.