# Pass a C++ member function to a C function

Tags: c++, c, c++11

We have a structure that accepts C function pointers:

```
int one(int x)
{
}

int two(int x)
{
}

struct Cstruct
{
    int (*fn1)(int);
    int (*fn2)(int);
};
```

Now I have a C++ class that has below methods:

```
class A
{
public:
    int one(int x)
    {
    }

    int two(int x)
    {
    }

    int three(int x)
    {
        struct Cstruct cstr = {&this->one, &this->two};
    }
};
```

While trying to initialize class A methods address to a instance of Cstruct compiler is giving error of an invalid conversion?

How can I assign the Class member function address to Cstruct?

Comment: Member functions pointers != function pointers.

Comment: Member functions are *not* equal to non-member functions. The big difference being that (non-static) member functions needs an *object* to be called on. Therefore they can't be used as pointers to non-member functions, and passed to C functions for callbacks. And no, using `this` when getting the pointer won't help, as it's still a pointer to the *function only*.

Comment: Function pointers are different from member function pointers.  You want to use the syntax `int (A::*fn1)(int);`.  You will also need an instance of `A` to call the function from.

Comment: Member functions have a hidden `this` as first parameter, so the type of `A::one` actually looks something like `int (*fn)(A*, int)`

Comment: There *could* be a way around the problem, if the structure have some kind of user-data member or pointer. Then you could set that pointer to the object, and have a function-pointer to a non-member function (or a `static` member function) which takes the user-data pointer and cast it to the proper type and call the actual member function.

Comment: [Wrapping C++ class API for C consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1590534/14065)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do it, because C++ pointer to a non-static member function is not compatible with a non-member function pointer type. This is because member functions require an additional argument - the object on which the member function needs to be called, which becomes `this` pointer inside the invocation.

If you make your member functions static, your code would compile. However, it would not necessarily do what you want to achieve, because `one` and `two` have no access to other non-static members of `A`.

A trick to passing member functions to C functions requires passing an additional `void*` pointer with the "registration" record, and having C code pass it back to your static callback functions:

```
struct Cstruct
{
    void *context; // Add this field
    int (*fn1)(void*, int);
    int (*fn2)(void*, int);
};

class A
{
public:
    static int oneWrap(void* ptr, int x)
    {
        return static_cast<A*>(ptr)->one(x);
    }

    static int twoWrap(void* ptr, int x)
    {
        return static_cast<A*>(ptr)->two(x);
    }

    int one(int x)
    {
    }

    int two(int x)
    {
    }

    int three(int x)
    {
        struct Cstruct cstr = {this, &this->oneWrap, &this->twoWrap};
    }
};
```

C code would need to pass the value of `context` to `fn1` and `fn2`:

```
cs.fn1(cs.context, 123);
cs.fn2(cs.context, 456);
```

Comment: Is there no other way to achieve the same - can we create an object of the class and then assign it?

Comment: @Programmer There is, but your C function needs to "cooperate". Please see the edit.